OpenCV: Unable to Stream from Webcam (Built-in and External Logitech C270)
I’m trying to test if I can stream my camera feed in OpenCV. I have two cameras connected to my laptop:

The built-in webcam.
An external Logitech C270 webcam.

Both cameras work fine when I use them in VLC or the Windows Camera app. However, I’m facing issues with OpenCV:

When I use cv2.VideoCapture(0), I get the error:
Error: Could not open webcam.
When I use cv2.VideoCapture(1), I don’t see any error, but the displayed frame is completely black. I suspect index 1 should be the correct index for my external camera.

Additionally:

When I run the code with index 1, the external camera becomes inaccessible in other programs, which makes sense since OpenCV takes control of the device.
I’ve ensured that Python 3.11 has permission to access the camera under Windows settings, and the camera usage indicator confirms that the camera is being used.
The issue doesn’t seem to be related to VS Code. I get the same behavior when running the script directly from the terminal.

I can’t figure out:

Why I can’t access my built-in webcam (index 0).
Why my external camera (index 1) shows a black screen in OpenCV.

Here’s my code:
import cv2

def main():
    print("Press 'q' to quit the program.")
    # Open a connection to the webcam (0 is the default camera)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Error: Could not open webcam.")
        return

    # Allow the camera to warm up
    cv2.waitKey(1000)

    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            print("Error: Could not read frame.")
            break

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Webcam Stream', frame)

        # Break the loop on 'q' key press
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

    # When everything is done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I would appreciate any advice on how to debug or resolve this issue. Are there additional configurations I should be checking? Is there a better way to test both cameras?
Thanks in advance!
EDIT:
I tried using ffmpeg to get more information about my camera. I installed the python-lib and run the following script:
from imageio_ffmpeg import get_ffmpeg_exe
import os

ffmpeg_path = get_ffmpeg_exe()

os.system(f'"{ffmpeg_path}" -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy')

I get this output:
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[dshow @ 00000211f34a91c0] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 00000211f34a91c0]  "Integrated Webcam"
[dshow @ 00000211f34a91c0]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_0c45&pid_6d13&mi_00#6&18c8350f&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 00000211f34a91c0]  "Logi C270 HD WebCam"
[dshow @ 00000211f34a91c0]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_046d&pid_0825&mi_00#7&1ef939b1&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 00000211f34a91c0]  "OBS Virtual Camera"
[dshow @ 00000211f34a91c0]     Alternative name "@device_sw_{860BB310-5D01-11D0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}\{A3FCE0F5-3493-419F-958A-ABA1250EC20B}"
[dshow @ 00000211f34a91c0] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 00000211f34a91c0]  "Mikrofon (3- Logi C270 HD WebCam)"
[dshow @ 00000211f34a91c0]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{2839ECB9-3054-4631-9391-CE0C2E6CADD4}"
[dshow @ 00000211f34a91c0]  "Microphone Array (Realtek(R) Audio)"
[dshow @ 00000211f34a91c0]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{EC1466BD-0BFF-46FD-960E-B7EAAD2B6787}"

After that I run the next script to get information about the camera modes:
import subprocess
from imageio_ffmpeg import get_ffmpeg_exe

def list_camera_modes(camera_name):
    ffmpeg_path = get_ffmpeg_exe()

    command = f'"{ffmpeg_path}" -f dshow -list_options true -i video="{camera_name}"'
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    camera_name = "Logi C270 HD WebCam"
    list_camera_modes(camera_name)

And I get the output:
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0] DirectShow video device options (from video devices)
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]  Pin "Capture" (alternative pin name "0")
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x960 fps=5 max s=1280x960 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x960 fps=5 max s=1280x960 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=5 max s=1280x720 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=5 max s=1280x720 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1024x768 fps=5 max s=1024x768 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1024x768 fps=5 max s=1024x768 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=800x600 fps=5 max s=800x600 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=800x600 fps=5 max s=800x600 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x480 fps=5 max s=640x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x480 fps=5 max s=640x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x360 fps=5 max s=640x360 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x360 fps=5 max s=640x360 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=320x240 fps=5 max s=320x240 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=320x240 fps=5 max s=320x240 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x960 fps=5 max s=1280x960 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x960 fps=5 max s=1280x960 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x960 fps=5 max s=1280x960 fps=5
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x960 fps=5 max s=1280x960 fps=5
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x720 fps=5 max s=1280x720 fps=5
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x720 fps=5 max s=1280x720 fps=5
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1024x768 fps=5 max s=1024x768 fps=5
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1024x768 fps=5 max s=1024x768 fps=5
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=800x600 fps=20 max s=800x600 fps=20
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=800x600 fps=20 max s=800x600 fps=20
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=5 max s=640x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=5 max s=640x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x240 fps=30 max s=320x240 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x240 fps=30 max s=320x240 fps=30
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x960 fps=5 max s=1280x960 fps=5
[dshow @ 0000023f579391c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x960 fps=5 max s=1280x960 fps=5

I believe the camera should work properly. I adjusted my cv2 script to match the supported modes of my camera:
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

width, height = 1280, 960
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

fps = 30
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'))

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Kamera konnte nicht geöffnet werden")
else:
    print(f"Kamera erfolgreich geöffnet mit {width}x{height} @ {fps} FPS")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Frame konnte nicht gelesen werden")
        break
    
    cv2.imshow("Kamera", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # 'q' zum Beenden
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Still same results.

Yeah, I know. But with index 1 is just get a black screen. I tried recording a mp4 file using the camera app provided by windows and I tried to stream this using the same scirpt, this works. I dont know why there is a black screen when using index 1

Im using Windows 11 Pro.  The webcam works fine when using VCL or a different software

crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/issue-unable-to-stream-webcam-properly-in-opencv/19502

the brand and model of built-in camera is relevant. and available video modes: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "video modes." I'm relatively new to OpenCV, so I tried specifying an API preference when using cv2.VideoCapture. When using CAP_DSHOW, I get the same result as before: just a black screen with index 1 when trying to use my external camera. When I use CAP_FFMPEG or CAP_IMAGES, I'm unable to detect any camera, and I receive an error. So do I need to install FFmpeg and use this api reference?

Regarding the internal camera, I can’t say much about it. I’m using a Dell XPS 13 with the built-in webcam. If it doesn’t work, it’s not a big deal—I was just curious why it’s not working either. What’s important is that the external camera works.

Regarding the cross-posting, I’m sorry if it’s an issue—I wasn’t aware that it’s discouraged. I need this for a project and ideally as soon as possible, so I thought it made sense to post it in two forums to increase the chances of getting help.

use ffmpeg to enumerate the device's video modes. these are independent of ffmpeg, but ffmpeg can tell us these. [edit] your question and add them. that could give us a clue as to why OpenCV can't get a picture from the camera.

Ok, thank you! I edited my question and added the modes. I hope this helps.

you can just get ffmpeg from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows. that python package is extra steps.

I see that the queried device supports 640x480 at 30 fps. that is what OpenCV tries by default. if the device didn't support that, OpenCV would have failed for this reason. since the device supports it, that is now ruled out as the reason for any failures.

likely either Windows itself or some logitech service program tries to control access to the camera. the blanking out of camera video could be a privacy feature. you should investigate this.

I'm not entirely sure if that's the issue. I can use the camera with other programs, and when I start my script, I can't use the camera in other programs anymore. To me, this indicates that the script allocates the camera. When I start the script, Windows Security also shows that Python 3.11 is currently using the camera, and the access permissions are enabled as well.

I think I found a solution. I'm using Avast Security and the option camera protection was activated. I deactivated this and now the internal camera works fine. I'm not able to try the external camera till Monday but I think this should solve the problem. Thank you so much @ChristophRackwitz!

if you feel like telling Avast off, you could let them know (bug report/issue) that they might want to show, instead of a blank picture, something hinting at the cause (Avast Security) and reason (privacy).

As it turns out, some privacy measure (Avast Security "Webcam Shield") blanked out the camera feed.
Details: https://support.avast.com/en-us/article/use-antivirus-webcam-shield/
